# Revering the int array using java for loop

Tags: java, arrays, integer, int, reverse

The code to return the integer array reversed.
I think its entirely correct, But its not working.

The code is not entering into the           for(int j=3; j==0; j--) loop.

CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int[] rev = new int[n];

  for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();   
      System.out.println( "Here"+ arr[i]);
      for(int j=3; j==0; j--)
       {
          System.out.println(j);
          System.out.print( "Resevre1 "+ rev[j]);
          if (j+i==3)
          {
          rev[j] = arr[3-i];
          System.out.print( "Resevre Here"+ rev[j]);
          }
       }
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Sample Input

> 4
>
> 1 4 3 2

Sample Output

> 2 3 4 1

Comment: `for(int j=3; j==0; j--)` means you tantalize `j` to 3 and execute the loop as long as `j` equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

The code wont go in the loop the condituon you have entered will always be false.

```
for(int j=3; j==0; j--)
```

inital value of j is 3 and the condition statement which needs to be true everytime you want your program to go inside the loop this  will always keep failling unless your condition statement
    j==0

satisfies.
As I can judge you are trying to run the loop in reverse 
You need to change the condition to 
    for(int j= 3; j>=0; j--)

depands how many times you want this loop to run revrse thrice or twice.

Answer (score 0):

CODE:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```